# Binding BitmapImage to Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, bitmapimage

I'm doing a project in WPF where user make cards and the program show this cards on the screen for the users moving this.

This Cards have a Name, a Description and can to have an Image or not. This Template is the next:

```
<Style x:Key="YellowCard" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:tarjeta}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Margin="1">
                            <StackPanel Background="Yellow">
                                <Image Name="image" Stretch="Fill" ... />
                                <Label
                                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:tarjeta}}, Path=Nombre}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                FontSize="10"/>
                                <Label
                                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:tarjeta}}, Path=Descripcion}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="Black"
                                FontSize="8"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Card class is the next:

```
class tarjeta : ContentControl, ICloneable
{
    private string nombre;
    private string descripcion;
    public ArrayList historial;
    private string estilo;
    byte[] arrayImagen;
    string nombreImagen;
    string strImagen;
    BitmapImage imagen;
    ImageSource imagenSource;

    public tarjeta()
    {
        nombre = "";
        descripcion = "";
        historial = new ArrayList();
    }

    public tarjeta(string name, string desc)
    {
        nombre = name;
        descripcion = desc;
        historial = new ArrayList();
        estilo = "YellowCard";
    }

    public tarjeta(string name, string desc, ArrayList hist)
    {
        nombre = name;
        descripcion = desc;
        historial = hist;
        estilo = "YellowCard";
    }

    public tarjeta(string name, string desc, ArrayList hist, string style)
    {
        nombre = name;
        descripcion = desc;
        historial = hist;
        estilo = style;
    }

    public tarjeta(string name, string desc, string nameImagen, string strImage, byte[] array)
    {
        nombre = name;
        descripcion = desc;
        historial = new ArrayList();
        nombreImagen = nameImagen;
        strImagen = strImage;
        arrayImagen = array;
        imagen = new BitmapImage();
    }

    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return this.nombre; }
        set { this.nombre = value; }
    }

    public string Descripcion
    {
        get { return this.descripcion; }
        set { this.descripcion = value; }
    }

    public string Estilo
    {
        get { return this.estilo; }
        set { this.estilo = value; }
    }

    public byte[] ArrayImagen
    {
        get { return this.arrayImagen; }
        set { this.arrayImagen = value; }
    }

    public string NombreImagen
    {
        get { return this.nombreImagen; }
        set { this.nombreImagen = value; }
    }

    public string StrImagen
    {
        get { return this.strImagen; }
        set { this.strImagen = value; }
    }

    public BitmapImage Imagen
    {
        get { return this.imagen; }
        set { this.imagen = value; }

    }

    public ImageSource ImagenSource
    {
        get { return this.Imagen as ImageSource; }
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }


    public BitmapImage crearImagen(byte[] imageData)
    {
        // crear un bitmap para la imagen               
        BitmapImage bitImg = new BitmapImage();
        try
        {
            // asignar los bytes obtenidos de la BBDD al bitmap                
            // se cogera el primer registro el campo 2 que contiene los bytes de la imagen
            bitImg.BeginInit();
            System.IO.Stream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData);
            bitImg.StreamSource = ms;
            bitImg.EndInit();
            bitImg.Freeze();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: No se puede obtener la imagen " + ex.Message);
        }

        return bitImg;
    }
}
```

Card's Information (Name, Description and Image) i obtain it from a .xml file.

The Question Is:
How I can do the binding Card's Image with Style's Image Control??
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you've done with the rest:

```
<Image Name="image" Stretch="Fill" 
Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
      AncestorType={x:Type local:tarjeta}}, Path=Imagen}"
```

You should call `crearImangen()` in constructor I think.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer but it don't work. crearImagen() work but the binding not work and the program not show the image.

Comment: @Miguel: is `crearImagen` calledin constructor?  If you are calling crearImagen later, you're going to need to implement either dependency property or `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `property changed` event in your `Imagen` property.

Comment: Now it's work!! the problem was when i read from .xml file, the program used other constructor without byte[], without strImagen and without Imagen. Thank you for your help!!